# How to apply advance django query set filters based on two different columns?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am new to django. I am working on a test project. Where I have a Model `CollectFee` with structure given below:
[image: model collect fee]

```
class CollectFee(models.Model):
    boarder = models.ForeignKey(Boarder, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    feetype = models.ForeignKey(FeeType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amountdue = models.PositiveIntegerField("amount Due")
    amountpaid = models.PositiveIntegerField("amount Paid")
    balance = models.PositiveIntegerField("Balance")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Collect Fee"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.boarder.name
```

I want to apply a query set in the views which will display all the records where `feetype_id` is not 2, when this record is excluded then also exclude those records which have the same `boarder_id` as of already excluded record.
For example, Exclude the second row as it has `feetype_id = 2` then also exclude the third row because it has the same `boarder_id` as of second row.

As I am new, I was able to just implement the filter below:

```
def feedue(request):
    last_fee_type = FeeType.objects.last()
    boarders = CollectFee.objects.exclude(feetype_id=last_fee_type)
    
    context = {'boarders':boarders}
    return render(request, 'fee-due.html', context)
```

Comment: Can you share actual `CollectFee` model?

Comment: Isn't it what you want? `..exclude(feetype_id=2).exclude(boarder_id=2)`?

Comment: Look at [Queryset method `exclude`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exclude)

Comment: You should not filter/query by hardcoded IDs. Imagine your instance with ID = 2 somehow happens to change to ID = 4 (maybe in a new database or some data migrations idk.) then you will introduce a bug in your program. If the instance with ID=2 has some specific properties maybe consider using those.

Comment: I have updated the question with the model code. Furthermore, the feetype value is not hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the many-to-one relationship with the through accessor like this:

```py
CollectFee.objects.exclude(boarder__collectfee__feetype=last_fee_type)
```

This expression essentially gets the Boarder from a particular CollectFee object, then all CollectFees associated with that Boarder and their FeeTypes, allowing you to exclude accordingly.

Comment: It works with a small issue. It does not display the boarders who have been assigned the last fee Type. It's OK.
But if a Boarder is not assigned the last fee type, then it shows that boarders names as many times as the feetypes have been assigned. E.g If a boarder is assigned two feetypes but not the last feetype, then it shows the border name twice.

Comment: Probably need to put `.filter(feetype=last_fee_type)` before the exclude expression

Comment: doing this does not show anything.

Comment: Are you sure `last_fee_type` is the one you want and has corresponding data? I try my code locally with your example data and it worked fine

Comment: Yeah. It has entries. And perfectly followed you.

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps

```
def feedue(request):
    excluded_objs = CollectFee.objects.filter(feetype_id=2)
    border_ids = [id.border_id for obj in excluded_objs]
    duefee = CollectFee.objects.exclude(boarder_id__in=border_ids)

    context = {'duefee': duefee}
    return render(request, 'fee-due.html', context)
```

Comment: It says: "name 'obj' is not defined"

Comment: sorry, you can try now. did you get the logic?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried but it says:
'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'border_id'

Please help.